# How to replace the icon in a Tkinter app?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Python 3.5.0 on Windows 10 and want to replace this:

[image: with something else.]

Comment: The solutions below seem NOT to work on Ubuntu or Raspberry Pi. Now that I look closer, I don't see icons in application title bars on linux anymore.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To change the icon you should use `iconbitmap` or `wm_iconbitmap` I'm under the impression that the file you wish to change it to must be an ico file.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap("myIcon.ico")
```

Comment: If it is in the same directory, then simply the file name will do. Otherwise put the whole filepath as the string.

Answer (score 23):

If you haven't an *icon.ico* file you can use an `ImageTk.PhotoImage(ico)` and [`wm_iconphoto`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.html#M36).

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

ico = Image.open('test.jpg')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ico)
root.wm_iconphoto(False, photo)

root.mainloop()
```

Note:

> If default is True, this is applied to all future created toplevels as
> well. The data in the images is taken as a snapshot at the time of
> invocation.

Detailed implementations under different OS:

- **On Windows**, the images are packed into a Windows icon structure. This
  will override an ico specified to wm iconbitmap, and vice versa.
- **On X**, the images are arranged into the _NET_WM_ICON X property, which
  most modern window managers support. A wm iconbitmap may exist
  simultaneously. It is recommended to use not more than 2 icons,
  placing the larger icon first.
- **On Macintosh**, this sets the Dock icon with the specified image.

[See more](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wm+iconphoto)

[Supported formats](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/photo.html#M4) since [TkVersion 8.6](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/244.md) of `tk.PhotoImage(filepath)`:

- PNG
- GIF
- PPM/PGM

Therefore code can be simplified with a `.png` file to:

```
import tkinter as tk 
root = tk.Tk() 
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'test.png')
root.wm_iconphoto(False, photo)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9):

### input for tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.title('Tk')
app.geometry('')

app.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\my.ico')
app.mainloop()
```

### input for pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w -F --add-binary "my.ico;." my.py
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, wich doesn't force you to use an ico file :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Pc\\Desktop\\icon.png'))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must not have favicon.ico in the same directory as your code or namely on your folder. Put in the full Pathname. For examples:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Python32\DLLs\py.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

This will work

Comment: There is no need to do so, you can just upload it from the current directory and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

## If you are using CustomTkinter:

```
app.wm_iconbitmap('yt.ico')
```

[CustomTkinter documentation](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('how to put icon ?')

root.iconbitmap('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\py.ico')
   
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way via Tcl command:

```
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', win._w, tk.PhotoImage(file=r"my_icon.png"))
window.mainloop()
```