# how to change an app icon in tkinter? I trayed to look online but it didn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm traying to make an app GUI using tkinter. how do I change the window icon?
I trayed to do:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap('app_icon.ico')
root.mainloop
```

Comment: Did you just renamed your picture with the suffix *.ico* or did you have *.ico* file downloaded/created/converted?

Comment: You may look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324528/13629335) and see if a working solution is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to show that path to the ico picture, try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.iconbitmap('/path/to/ico/app_icon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I trayed to do that. its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, you can check this for your scenario

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

p1 = PhotoImage(file = "/path/to/ico/app_icon.ico") 
  
root.iconphoto(False, p1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That did not worked for me for some reason

Comment: @HeaG Can you tell me what error you are getting ?

Comment: couldn't open "app_icon.ico": no such file or directory

Comment: Is that 'ico' file saved in the same folder as your python file @HeaG