# on Ubuntu, Not able to insert icon on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Not able to add `icons` in ubuntu tkinter code.

```
from tkinter import *
    
root = Tk()

root.title("Images and Icons")
    
icon = PhotoImage(file='tv_icon.ico')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)
root.mainloop()
```

Output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "icons.py", line 8, in <module>
    icon = PhotoImage(file='tv_icon.ico')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "tv_icon.ico"
```

Comment: `.ico` is not supported by `tkinter.PhotoImage()`, use PNG image instead.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139792/11106801) implies that if you use `root.iconbitmap(...)`, you can use `.ico` files. Also most of the time, it's not a good idea to use `.tk.call(...)`. Usually `tkinter` defines a normal function that you can call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.3.

I don't know why this is happening, but for me this worked:

1. Convert `.ico` file to `.png` file
2. `root.iconphoto(False, PhotoImage(file='./icon.png'))`