# Custom Taskbar Icon in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, icons, taskbar

I am working in tkinter. I want to create a custom taskbar icon in tkinter without toplevel and i also want to when i hover on the taskbar icon my application preview show the application body.
So please help me

[image]

I want the taskbar icon like this

Comment: it should show the preview of the window, as for the icon, just set the icon using `.iconphoto` or `.iconbitmap` whichever you need, both methods are documented. Also you should provide a [mre]

Comment: The `.iconify()` call with do that, but clicking it will still bring the window back up.

Comment: I did find a module out there for making system tray icons, but I don't believe that will work for you. https://pystray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to replace the icon in a Tkinter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137829/how-to-replace-the-icon-in-a-tkinter-app)

Comment: I want to delete the frame of the window without deleting the icon from taskbar.
like wm_overrideredirect(1) function can delete the frame but also remove the icon of the taskbar.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.