# Why isn’t .ico file defined when setting window’s icon tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code, but why isn’t `.ico` file defined when setting window’s icon?

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()

root.title("Tkinter App")

root.iconbitmap('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main\yazilimfoto\Ataturk1.jpg')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace the icon in a Tkinter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137829/how-to-replace-the-icon-in-a-tkinter-app)

Comment: *.jpg* isn't supported by tkinter. Refer to my answer in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

there are some problems in your code

the icon you are setting is in .jpg format.
then use

```
ico = Image.open('test.jpg')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ico)
root.wm_iconphoto(False, photo)
```

and then

```
root.iconbitmap(photo)
```

and it will work. remember that you don't need to insert the entire file path (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Main\yazilimfoto\Ataturk1.jpg) but only the file path in your .py file directory