# meaning of the parameters of the root.tk.call() method

Tags: tkinter

Could someone explain to me the meaning of the parameters of this root.tk.call() method?

this method is  for to define the tkinter application icon. As I recently changed from windows to linux I'm having this difficulty , because in windows it was a very simple method.

code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

root.geometry("600x400+400+200")

root.title('MInha aplicação GUI')

**root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='images_gallery_21525.png'))**

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that you can use the python implementation for the most time. Under the hood tkinter uses these calls to provide a high level interface in python. [`root.wm_iconphoto(reference)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324528/13629335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical documentation can be found in the [man page of the wm iconphoto command](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/wm.htm#M50).

- `wm` is the name of the command being run.
- `iconphoto` is the name of the subcommand of the `wm` command.
- `root._w`, is the internal name for the widget that should use the image.
- `tk.PhotoImage(...)` creates a `PhotoImage` which will appear on the window.