# Confused about "iconphoto()" boolean propertys and use in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I thought when I set `iconphoto()` at False the logo for the tkinter app would not be displayed. But it was displayed. True and False both displayed the logo in the exact same way, so I was wondering what the purpose of this is. And what one I should use just for displaying the app logo. I also want to know if in the case of `iconphoto()` True and False may have a different purpose apart from being a boolean value.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

icon = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\botta\\Downloads\\python.png")
window.iconphoto(False,icon)


window.mainloop()
```

I was thinking when I set `iconphoto()` at False the logo for the tkinter app the logo would not be displayed, but that was not the case. True and False did the same thing for some reason.

Comment: That isn't what the first argument is for; what documentation told you it was?

Comment: I just want to know if I should use true or false when using iconphoto() and what the difference is.

Comment: That's what documentation is for.

Comment: [Here it is mentioned that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324528/13629335) *If default is True, this is applied to all future created toplevels as well. The data in the images is taken as a snapshot at the time of invocation.*

Comment: Which says nothing about whether or not the icon would be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the boolean first argument (named `default`) determines if this image should be used only for this window (if the value is `False`) or used as the default for all windows (if the value is `True`).